# Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture.cancel(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os

I am trying to figure out how to get sensors data from Health Services on Wear OS.

I'm trying to run samples ([Passive Data Sample](https://github.com/android/health-samples/tree/main/PassiveData)) from the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/passive) on Emulator for Wear OS API 30 (He is available in [Beta Android Studio Arctic Fox](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)), but I get this error:

```
2021-07-02 16:55:54.041 7172-7200/com.example.passivedata E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.passivedata, PID: 7172
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture.cancel(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2392)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2370)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2353)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2295)
    at androidx.health.services.client.impl.IPassiveMonitoringApiService$Stub$Proxy.registerDataCallback(IPassiveMonitoringApiService.java:318)
    at androidx.health.services.client.impl.ServiceBackedPassiveMonitoringClient$registerDataCallbackInternal$serviceOperation$1.execute(ServiceBackedPassiveMonitoringClient.kt:122)
    at androidx.health.services.client.impl.ipc.Client$3.execute(Client.java:222)
    at androidx.health.services.client.impl.ipc.internal.ServiceConnection.execute(ServiceConnection.java:243)
    at androidx.health.services.client.impl.ipc.internal.ServiceConnection.enqueue(ServiceConnection.java:200)
    at androidx.health.services.client.impl.ipc.internal.ConnectionManager.handleMessage(ConnectionManager.java:123)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: The repository already has [an issue](https://github.com/android/health-samples/issues/3) reported regarding this.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs yes, it's me. But no one comments(

Comment: I have tried this on my side but I don't have issues when running 'Passive data sample' on API 30

Answer (score 1):

change enableHermes from false to true in your android/app/build.gradle file

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true
]
```

add these line in android/app/src/main/java/com/yourProjectName/MainApplication.java

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;

@Override
protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
    return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();
}
//if this is not exist then also add this
@Override
protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index";
}
```

and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update this package

> react-native-reanimated

```
npm i react-native-reanimated@2.2.4
```

after installing this version of the package, just restart your simulator.